# CardView cardBackgroundColor / cardCornerRadius is not working. In short none of the CardView properties seem to be reflecting

Tags: android

I started designing a sample login page, but got stuck in the CardView section. The backgrounder and `app:cardCornerRadius` properties are not reflecting. The rest all worked fine but issue came while changing the color of card view. The default, which I learned is white, wasn't getting reflected.

No corner radius or background color change is showing up:

[image: No corner radius or background color change is showing up.]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="538dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/smiletrain_big" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="417dp"
    android:background=""
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="375dp"
    android:background=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="25dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Adding android:background to cardview only helps to change the cardview color but no help for cardCornerRadius.

Comment: Alright, I got to know there is this error: - android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache) classes not instantiated. Now all the solutions suggest to add dependency: implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0' which I have already added, still troubling with the above mentioned error.